# SwiftUI Tabview - Missing argument for parameter 'tab' in call

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, tabview

I am trying to play around with the new TabView from swift but I keep receiving this error:

> "Missing argument for parameter 'tab' in call".

Can you help me figure out the source of this error?

Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct View1: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            HStack {
                PageView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            TabView {
                ForEach(0..<30) { i in
                    ZStack {
                        Color.black
                        Text("Row: \(i)").foregroundColor(.white)
                    }.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0, style: .continuous))
                }
                .padding(.all, 10)
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 200)
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            Text("something")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of error:

[image]

Comment: Unable to reproduce with the provided code. `TabViews` are not very flexible if you are trying to delete/add in another `View` that could be the issue.

Comment: Compiled ok with Xcode 12.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `TabView` is a custom component (judging by Xcode syntax highlighting).

Try using SwiftUI explicitly:

```
SwiftUI.TabView {
    // ...
}
```